# StringToWordVector filter under weka

Tags: filter, weka, document-classification

My data are passed through StringToWordVector filter. StringToWordVector can output binary presence/absence indicators, word frequencies or TF-IDF scores.  what is the default output of this filter under weka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the options specified in this [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html),

```
-C
Output word counts rather than boolean word presence.
```

the default output is boolean word presence, and that can be changed by passing it arguments such as `-C`.